# How to solve error by compiler while running custom exception in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, try-catch

I have written following code to test custom exceptions in the dart using visual studio code.
(referring tutorial from YouTube) 
 I am not getting the desired output as shown in the tutorial.

```
void main(){

    try {
        depositMoney(-200);
    } catch (e) {
        print(e.errorMessage());
    } finally {
        print("FINALLY")
    }
}

class DepositException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage() {
    return "You cannot enter amount less than 0";
  }
}

void depositMoney(int amount) {
  if(amount < 0) {
    throw new DepositException();
  }
}
```

Output shown was

```
bin/code18.dart:6:17: Error: The method 'errorMessage' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'errorMessage'.
        print(e.errorMessage());
```

Please help me solve this problem
...
Desired output:

```
You cannot enter amount less than 0
FINALLY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same. I have resolved it by mentioning the Custom Exception class while initialing the catch block.

Find the code snippets below:

```
void main(){

    try {
        depositMoney(-200);
    } on DepositException catch (e) {
        print(e.errorMessage());
    } finally {
        print("FINALLY");
    }
}

class DepositException implements Exception {
  String errorMessage() {
    return "You cannot enter amount less than 0";
  }
}

void depositMoney(int amount) {
  if(amount < 0) {
    throw new DepositException();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should limit the catch with with "on" then, instead of checking the type in the body:  "on DespositException catch (e)"... then others won't be snarfed up erroneously.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't know this way. I have modified the codes. 

Comment: You could also implement an abstract class that extends Exception that has errorMessage, and then implement concrete classes for each specific exception you want, and "on MyBaseException catch(e)" to provide a class of exceptions that follow the same protocol.